# parse json String to a Entity class

Tags: java

```
{"field": {"11815": {"name": "email","value": "snow.fx@qq.com"},"11816": {"name": "storeid","value": "11"},"12116": {"name": "idcardtypeid","value": "1"},"12117": {"name": "idcardno","value": "320282199207071967"}},"birthday": "1992-7-7","name": "cccc","gender": 2,"openid": "90738","mobile": "1000"}
```

this is the json string, I wanna parse it to a entity class, define like:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Userinfo(){String name; int gender; .... ; JSONObject field}
```

I used ObjectMapper to parse, code is:

```
Userinfo userinfo = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonStr ,Userinfo.class)
```

but it still give error message 'Unrecognized field "11216", not marked as i ignorable'.

"birthday", "name", "mobile", "openid", easy to solve.
but "field" has "11815","11816","12116","12117", I can't define a variable named "11815", it's illegal in Java

Comment: Show your entity class and the code you tried.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java

Comment: @BrentWashburne class and code is above all

Comment: @NamanGala : thanks, i‘ve seen that question, and tried, but this question is a bit special, how to deal with the "field" part efficency

Answer (score 0):

Create a class with the field names representing Key names and create object initializing the fields with extracted values. If you have multiple records you can create a list of the objects.

Answer (score 0):

this is my entity class

```
public class userinfo(){
    String name; 
    int gender; ...; 
    Map<String, Map<String, Object>> field;
}
```

All variables are 'private' type, and getter/setter is essential.